# Bootstrap Navbar not working correctly: AngularCLI

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-cli

I included bootstrap into my angularcli project but when I try to include a navbar none of the elements are working correctly. I am using a standard boostrap navbar example from the website but it looks weird:

[image]

What is wrong with my project that is making the navbar not load correctly?

**navbar.component.html**

[image]

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```js
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some known issues in bootstrap 4 especially in navbar implemenation

Hence uou have to install bootstrap `bootstrap@3.3.7`

if you are using npm then the following libraries is best recommonded

```
 npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save

npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 tether jquery --save
```

In .angular-cli.json file  add the dependencies

```
"styles":[
"styles.css",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
],

"scripts":[
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],
```

Use the following HTML

```
 <nav class="navbarnavbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-togglecollapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Togglenavigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Angular5Website</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapsenavbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navnavbar-nav">
    <li class="active"> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse-->
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: It stil lhas a problem ill post a picture of the new look

Comment: Try the bootstrap 3.3.7 example navbar component. I have added the sample HTML for your kind reference.

Comment: that worked! Why is all of bootstraps documentation not working?

Comment: glad it helped!!. I was scratching my head to implement this. Not sure why the documentation was not up to date. But after three hours of scratching my head, I got the above solution.

Comment: like only one of the navbar elements

Comment: Including jQuery just to make collapse working... funny until it's my project.

Answer (score 13):

The code below shows how to implement the navbar in Angular with [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) and Bootstrap 4. You can see it at work in [**this plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PlGTWzSGqawgQC2wfKp8?p=preview).

- The `ng-bootstrap` library is developped for Angular, and does not require jQuery
- Using Bootstrap 4, you should [replace](https://medium.com/@lukaszholeczek/how-to-upgrade-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-to-bootstrap-4-beta-d43b4210f2a3) `navbar-toggleable-md` with `navbar-expand-md`
- The `ngbCollapse` directive is used to show/hide the dropdown menu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" (click)="isNavbarCollapsed = !isNavbarCollapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div [ngbCollapse]="isNavbarCollapsed" class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to use Bootstrap 4 navbar with Angular 5.

Answer (score 11):

**navbar.component.html:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" (click)="toggleNavbarCollapsing()">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a routerLink="/" class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse" [class.collapse]="navbarCollapsed">
      ...
```

**navbar.component.ts:**

```
navbarCollapsed = true;

toggleNavbarCollapsing() {
    this.navbarCollapsed = !this.navbarCollapsed;
}
```

Comment: worked for me in angular 12, Thanks @Aleksander

Answer (score 0):

Just add to index.html head  link to css and js

Bootstrap 5.2 Angular 13

link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous"

script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous" /script

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).