# Angular ng-bootstrap carousel not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to implement ngbd-carousel-basic in my Angular project. I just want to place it in the home.component for now. However, this is what I get after I tried following the code in documentation (albeit editing the file from html/ts to .component.html and .component.ts)

[image]

So, I am an Angular noob. So perhaps I forgot to include a step? Here are the steps I took so far:

1. Inside **app.module.ts**: Imported NgbdCarouselBasic from my file path. Declared it as a declaration. Import NgbModule, and within `@NgModule`, `import NgbModule.forRoot()`.

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

// Own components
import {NgbdCarouselBasic} from './shared/carousel/carousel-basic.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ViewAllRecordsComponent,
    NgbdCarouselBasic
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TableModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    TimeService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2. Inside **home.component.html**:

```
<ngbd-carousel-basic></ngbd-carousel-basic>
```

---

Here are my dependencies. Maybe something is incompatible and I did not realise?

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.4",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  "postcss": "^6.0.21",
  "primeng": "^5.2.4",
  "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
  "tether": "^1.4.3",
  "webpack": "^3.11.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
},
```

Comment: where did you give your image sources ? try to put your html code too

Comment: You need to upgrade to Bootstrap 4 in order to use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). According to your dependencies, you are now using Bootstrap 3.3.7.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Ah yes, ng-bootstrap does require Bootstrap 4. However, I had this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735689/bootstrap-navbar-not-working-correctly-angularcli hence I downgraded... Looks like I'll need an alternative way to have both navbar and carousel then?

Comment: It turns out that I gave [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48736308/1009922) to that other question. Did you try it?

Comment: Ended up just using ngx-bootstrap instead of ng-bootstrap and that works well, since it supports both Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4. Haven't tried your solution atm :/ At least my problem is resolved now. @ConnorsFan

Comment: Too bad that the accepted answer to the other question suggests downgrading to Bootstrap 3, which is not necessary

Answer (score 2):

Need to add bootstrap css in `style.css` file by adding below line:
   `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`