# Navbar collapse with Bootstrap doesn't work in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've created an Angular 4 app on top of a blockchain. It has to be responsive.
The hamburger button for collapsing and spreading the navbar doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/home']">I-Talent</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
```

This is my angular-cli:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "demo-simple"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

And this is my index.html:

```
<!--  Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
        See LICENSE in the source repository root for complete license information. -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Microsoft Graph Connect sample</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I've added jQuery everywhere I could to no avail.

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any console error ? Can you make a [mcve] ?

Comment: Hello, no console error. And what do you mean with example? It's just a Navbar with a hamburger button that doesn't work.

Comment: I mean reproduce it on stackblitz, this way we can test the behavior. Right now I don't see any issue in your code, you import the style, the scripts and all that is required for bootstrap. So you should make an example that proves that it doesn't work.

Comment: You need `popper.js` too. Read the [getting started docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js).

Comment: I recommend using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), an Angular implementation of Bootstrap 4. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48736308/1009922).

Comment: The `data-target` on your hamburger button doesn't match the ID of your menu. You're targeting `#navbarSupportedContent` but your menu is `#navbarNav`

Comment: @RobertC That was it. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment to your original post, the issue is that your `data-target` value does not match the actual `id` you've specified for your dropdown menu.

If you are targeting `#navbarSupportedContent` as in the below code:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Then your `.collapse` wrapper must have the same `id`:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

Where currently you are using `navbarNav`