# Property 'sectionsnap' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

Am getting issue when i add jquery code in ts file. (already i have include jquery)

Issue:
Property 'sectionsnap' does not exist on type 'JQuery HTMLElement'

jquery:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.sectionsnap = function( options ) {alert();
        var settings = $.extend({
            'delay'             : 100 // time dilay (ms)
            , 'selector'        : ".sec" // selector
            , 'reference'       : .9 // % of window height from which we start
            //, 'animationTime' : 400  animation time (snap scrolling)
            , 'offsetTop'       : 0 // offset top (no snap before scroll reaches this position)
            , 'offsetBottom'    : 0 // offset bottom (no snap after bottom - offsetBottom)
        }, options);        

        var $wrapper = this
        , direction = 'down'......
        ..................................
```

Comment: How do you your jquery import? You might need to extend its interface, or `declare let $ : any`; (but you'll loose types)

Comment: import * as sectionsnap from '../../assets/js/sectionsnap.js';  is it right?

Comment: How do you import jquery ? See here if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821320/bootstrap-w-angular-error-collapse-is-not-a-function/49822252#49822252