# How to use bootstrap navbar and dropdown (with angular 7)?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, navbar

I try this but when i click to `Dropdown link` nemu, nothing happens.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="dashboard">dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="calendar">calendar</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="manager">manager</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">

        </ul-->
    </div>
</nav>
```

**EDIT:**

I use https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview and [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) do not present.

Comment: With `ng-bootstrap`, you can manage the dropdown menu with the `ngbCollapse` directive, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48736308/1009922).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found in the [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview) documentation that [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) did not exist. So I added jQuery and it works.

```
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install jquery --save
```

and add this in angular.json (Angular 7):

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

probably you shouldn't include bootstrap.min.js in project (jquery and popper.js too).

```
"styles":[
"styles.css",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
],

"scripts":[
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/popper.js",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],
```

Comment: sorry, I add `"scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]` but do not work

Comment: you should add Jquery, bootstrap wrote based on jquery, and for nav it used popper too

Comment: you can see this too, [Duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48736103/2126355)

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to add **jquery, pooper and bootstrap JS** in your project, you can do like that, i added example of navbar and btn-group

**explanation**

```
show class is use to show menu of dropdown
```

when you click on **anchor** tag, **show** variable toggle and that contains boolean type ( specified in *.ts* file ). at time **div.dropdown-menu** check for **show** class and if its false it cant be shown or vice versa.

**app.component.html**

> In navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">List 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">List 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" (click)="show=!show">Dropdown</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" [ngClass]="{show: show === true}">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

> In btn-group

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" (click)="show=!show">Action</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" [ngClass]="{show: show === true}">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    show: boolean = false;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work because i think there is an issue with the popper.js, i had same issue but i was able to fix it... Try this in your angular.json

import the scripts

```
"./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
```

it should work